# new-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsS.Runtime.Application]: verify that the assembly containing

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have 3 line of code in powershell. I am trying to load and create object in script to call my SSIS package. But I am getting certain error.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:/Test/Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll")
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:/Test/Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll")
        $ssisApplication = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsS.Runtime.Application")
```

First line executes properly. 
Second line give error as :

> Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 
>   'file:///D:\Test\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a 
>   program with an incorrect format.

Third line giving error as :

> Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsS.Runtime.Application]: verify that the assembly containing 
>   this type is loaded.

Can any one please help resolve this issue. I m stuck past 3 4 days on this .

Comment: I was using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find missing dependencies. Perhaps it might be helpful for you too.

Comment: **Disclaimer**: use with caution (as every third party .exe) as I don't know much about this tool  - just used it once and it helped.